# Change FROM Name with Postfix

Tags: postfix

Using Postfix on Ubuntu 16 with google smtp server.

Everything works fine. The only problem is that I can't seem to find out how to change the FROM name in postfix. I have rewritten the email address successfully in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` using:

```
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

is there a similar rule to rewrite the FROM name ?

UPDATE

After reading the postfix manual, it is desirable not to alter the message headers. However, how can I tell postfix not to write any message headers and use whatever names i have set up in Google Aps ?

Comment: The `From:` header should ideally be set by the sending client and not be modified by the transporting server, but see http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Comment: Ok will have a look. I am not sure if Google Apps allows you to do that (i have a paid account).